# In BigQuery, how would you calculate monthly & daily totals using two date columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say that I have this simple query (the two date columns are TIMESTAMP):

```
SELECT
Song_Name, Artist_Name, Album_Name, Genre, Sub_Genres, Song_Length_Seconds, On_Platform_DateTime, Off_Platform_DateTime
FROM Music_Platform.Music_Data
```

And the first 4 rows of the table that would result:

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Using the two date columns, I want to be able to sum 'Song_Length_Seconds' for every month and day for which all the songs would be available (between the two dates in the TIMESTAMP columns).

For example (using the screenshot), just looking at the first 4 rows and only at the month of 2020-06, this would only include the first 3 rows, totaling 739.8 seconds.

I initially began with generating a temporary month table, but I'm unsure how to proceed or if this is even the best method:

```
with
  months as (
    select format_date('%Y-%m', month_start) month_key
    from unnest(
      generate_date_array('2020-01-01', '2022-12-01', interval 1 month)
    ) month_start
  )
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The first row is available for 26 days in June, so I would expect the value to be `26 * 242.2` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH table AS (
    SELECT 242.4 Song_Length_Seconds, TIMESTAMP '2020-06-05 11:00:00 UTC' On_Platform_DateTime
    union all
    SELECT 240.6 Song_Length_Seconds, TIMESTAMP '2020-06-17 05:00:00 UTC' On_Platform_DateTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 256.8 Song_Length_Seconds, TIMESTAMP '2020-06-24 05:00:00 UTC' On_Platform_DateTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 380.4 Song_Length_Seconds, TIMESTAMP '2020-07-21 05:00:00 UTC' On_Platform_DateTime
)
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM On_Platform_DateTime) year
    , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM On_Platform_DateTime) month
    , SUM(Song_Length_Seconds) Sum_Song_Length_Seconds
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    year
    , month
```